# Newman-Penrose null tetrad basis

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

In the Newman-Penrose formalism, generally, one sets $\bar{m^\mu}$ as the complex conjugate of $m^\mu$. Is this needed? Or can I define a fourth vector $p^\mu$ that obey the same restrictions of $\bar{m^\mu}$?

Comment: For real lorentzian space-time, the metric is real, so your fourth tetrad $p$ must be complex conjugate of $m$